# Использование COUNT для уникальных значений

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть таблица:

[image]

Необходимо узнать количество человек в каждом районе и получить:

[image]

Если сделать:

```
select id, count(*) [кол-во] from table1
group by id
order by id
```

получим:

```
id кол-во
1  2
2  2
```

Как сделать, чтобы count считал только уникальные сочетания (Имя-Фамилия)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, count(distinct имя+фамилия) 
from таблица1
group by id;
```

Comment: так, по-моему, не сработает, або `count` работает только с полями, но не выражениями.

Comment: А если проверить?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. 
Если у вас есть возможность добавить в Таблицу 2 графу данные гражданина, то можно попробовать сделать так:

```
select DISTINCT RTRIM(table1.familiya) + ' ' + RTRIM(table1.imya) AS 
  'Данные гражданина'  ,  id, count(*) [кол-во]   
from table1 group by id order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
select 
   t1.id, count(distinct t1.namesurname) from (
      select id, concat([имя], [фамилия]) as namesurname from 'таблица1') t1
   )
```

Не проверял/не отлаживал - в синтаксисе мог и налажать, но идея, надеюсь, понятна.

Comment: плохо, если имя и фамилия составные (испанцы и иже с ними) - может совпасть с другим человеком.